# provideDebugConfigurations not getting called

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I am using the vscode-mock-debug git as the basis for my work.

Activation event is OnDebug, although same result

I implement provideDebugConfigurations in my DebugConfigurationProvider and its not getting called.

```
provideDebugConfigurations(folder: WorkspaceFolder | undefined, token?: CancellationToken): DebugConfiguration[] {
 return [...my data in here];
}
```

the resolveDebugConfiguration (the original from mock-debug) is called, I can set a breakpoint. However the provideDebugConfigurations is never getting reached. build 1.36 of vsce. am I missing something obvious ?

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer from the vscode team: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78362

I have investigated this and it is expected behavior.

Namely, provideDebugConfigurations is only called then the debug configurations are needed to generate a launch.jsonfile. If you click on the configure command the provideDebugConfigurations will get nicely called.
However if you do not have a launch.json and you simply press Debug Start, vscode will try to start debugging without using debug configurations, but using one on the fly provided by the resolveDebugConfiguration call.

More about this can be found in our docs https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/debugger-extension

Thus closing this as designed.

Comment: you should add launch.js configuration to resolve the issue then